# Custom Property validation message code in User Control

Tags: c#, validation, properties, user-controls

How to add a **validation code** for a custom `Property` defined in a `UserControl`. Consider the following piece of code:

```
 public class Date

{
    private int month = 7;  // Backing store 

    public int Month
    {
        get
        {
            return month;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((value > 0) && (value < 13))
            {
                month = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It will check that `Month` value be between 1 and 12, but I want to an **Invalid input message** be shown up too in case it's invalid. Any ideas ?

Comment: it can be done in the place where you are accessing this property.

Answer (score 2):

If value is not between 1 and 12 you can throw e.g. an `InvalidOperationException` and handle it in your main thread.

```
public int Month
{
    get
    {
        return month;
    }
    set
    {
        if ((value > 0) && (value < 13))
        {
            month = value;
        }
        else throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid month");
    }
}
```

Then something like...

```
private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      date.Month = Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.Text);
   }
   catch(InvalidOperationException ex)
   {
      e.Cancel = true;
      textBox1.Select(0, textBox1.Text.Length);

      // some message about invalid value
   }
}
```

where `textBox1_Validating` is the validating event handler of the textbox.